# Connecting headphones to bluetooth to the same computer twice (in different operating systems)

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth

I have two pair of headphones, both can connect to multiple devices (Bose QC 35 and Bose 700). I have a computer that has 2 installations of Windows 10 and in both I'm seeing the same behaviour: when I connect to one of the two installations, the other one is automatically removed from the list of devices. This is not because I'm reaching the max amount of devices. Do you know what's going on? how to fix it?

I don't know much about Bluetooth, but I imagine the hardware of that computer has an id and the headphones can't have two pairings to the same id? something similar to a MAC? Is it possible to change it by software?

Comment: Reading the manuals, both seem to indicate that "multiple connections" are for "mobile devices" through related mobile-only software (Android and iOS).

Comment: @Anaksunaman I have both connected to two computers just fine (on top of that single computer that I use with two installations of Windows).

Comment: What is the Bluetooth on the PC?  You can have a multi-slave piconet.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat I'm sorry, but I don't understand the question. What do you mean what is the bluetooth? Do you mean what's the hardware implementation?

Comment: Try: Connect with one Windows instance, then export registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\BTHPORT\Parameters\Devices` and import it on the other Windows instance (backup the key first on the second Windows).

Comment: Are you saying that you are dual booting? And the headphones are "forgotten" after a reboot?

Comment: @harrymc I tried that, a few times, back and forth and it's still the same issue.

Comment: @TomYan my headphones lose OS 1 when I connect to OS 2, the OSs don't forget the headphones. I need to remove them to re-add them actually.

Comment: This might be the solution: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/255510/17660

Answer (score 0):

A Bluetooth adapter has an address similar to a MAC address. Like MAC addresses, I believe they are unique. Checking my machine which has an Intel WiFi adapter, the BT address is +4 relative to the WiFi MAC address. For example my Wifi addpter MAC has a last byte of D7 and the BT adapter is the same except for the last byte being DB.

To find your BT MAC address: open Device Manager, expand the BlueTooth section. This lists every BT device that you have connected and it also lists your adapter. Mine is shown as Intel Wireless Bluetooth. Right click that and select Properties, select the Advanced tab and the BT MAC is shown as Address in the same format as a WiFi MAC.

I don't know any way to change that address using Win 10 tools. However, There are some programs available which suggest they can change the address. Google for "win 10 how to change the bluetooth MAC" without the quotes and one offering is https://macaddresschanger.com/ . That site also has a lookup function to find the manufacturer of a BT device. Note that this program is limited to certain brands of adapters.

This question has surfaced before and the suggestion above by harrymc may also do the trick. If I recall correctly, that one sets up both systems to appear identical to your headphones.

Answer (score 0):

The following method may make both Windows instances treat the headphones
in an identical manner:

- Connect the headphones to one Windows instance
- Use `regedit` to export as a `.reg` file the following
  registry key:
  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\BTHPORT\Parameters\Devices`
- Boot the other Windows instance
- Export this same registry key for backup
  (I'm a bit unclear if you'll need to delete all its sub-keys)
- Use `regedit` to import the `.reg` file (or just double-click the file)
- Reboot.

Comment: I tried this a few times back and forth, but it still doesn't connect to the other OS and I have to remove them and re-add them.

Comment: When you said "removed from the list of devices" - which list was it and where is it found?

Comment: The list of bluetooth connected devices in Windows 10.

Comment: In addition to the registry key in my answer, do also registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\BTHENUM` and key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\BTH`. I suggest first deleting all existing sub-keys in the target (after taking backup).

Comment: I couldn't delete all the keys, in some cases, it says "access denied" even though I was logged in as admin. Sadly, despite making them the same in both computers, when I connect my headphones to computer A, then B and then I go back to A, it says "driver error" when I try to connect, which is new.

Comment: This might be the solution: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/255510/17660